# The type or namespace name could not be found in MSBuild but works in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, exceldatareader

I'm trying to build my multi-project solution from the dotnet CLI, but one project throws error CS0246. I have no problems building it from Visual Studio. The error is encountered on line 1 in the file using the NuGet package that is causing the problem:

```
using ExcelDataReader;
```

The error encountered:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ExcelDataReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I run the following commands from cmd:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet clean
dotnet build
```

What makes building from Visual Studio different from building from the CLI? What can I do to solve the 'missing' assembly?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Polly' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` in Jenkin build, because there was version mismatch in project reference and Nuget packages config file.

Project reference `.csproj` file contains reference of 7.**2.0**

```
<Reference Include="Polly, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c8a3ffc3f8f825cc, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
     <HintPath>..\packages\Polly.7.2.0\lib\net472\Polly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

But Neget `packages.config` file contains 7.**1.0**

```
<package id="Polly" version="7.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
```

(May by someone has updated the `.csproj` file manually)

To resolve this issue:

- Uninstall the library package using Nuget Package Manager.
- Save All.
- Install the library package again using Nuget Package Manager.

Verify the changes to ensure that the reference and config files have the same package reference.